# iniciante que nao sabe fazer request/BEGGINER TRYING TO REQUEST

Tags: javascript, json

estou fazendo um projeto em que preciso acessar a ID de um usuário (o banco de dados é só um obj por enquanto). porem ao tentar fazer um destructin:

**---> const {id}= req.body; <---**

```
let found= false;

database.users.map(user=>{
    if(user.id===id){
        found = true;
        return res.json(database.users);
    }
})
```

minha ID do destructin não possui valor algum. eu tenho um Login para o projeto, e quando logo com o usuário possuo uma id. esse Obj do usuário é dado como resposta após o Login, e deve ser comparado com a ID do user.id para meu projeto dar certo. mas nao estou sabendo utilizar a informacao que meu Login expele.

meu "login" é isso aqui, caso seja util:

```
app.post("/signin",(req,res)=>{
if(req.body.email=== database.users[0].email && 
   req.body.password===database.users[0].password){
    res.json(database.users[0]);
}else{
    res.status(400).json("erro de login");
}

})
```

desde já agradeco ;)

Answer (score 0):

Você já tentou utilizar o método find() ?
Ele vai te retornar o primeiro elemento que ele encontrar que atenda a sua requisição

```
const found = database.users.find( user => user.id === id );
```

Se a variável found receber algum valor ela passa a não retornar false, caso não encontre ela vai continuar vazia

**edit:
Se não for esse o problema, tente exemplificar melhor que eu dou uma mão

Comment: gostei do método, mas essa condicional continua dando um valor indefinido. o problema em si é no proprio id do (const {id}= req.body;), ele é undefined, mas deveria conter o id que vem da resposta do meu login.

eu entro no aplicativo, com email e senha e o login responde o obj correspondente a esses dados, é desse obj que eu quero o id do distructin, mas não estou sabendo referenciar eu acho

Comment: o id do req.body vem da requisição, do arquivo json que você manda via post...